# Do we have to have to enable MSDTC to use TransactionScope?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, transactionscope

Do we have to have to enable MSDTC to use TransactionScope?

I am using TransactionScope and I had error message telling me that the MSDTC not enabled.  So I have enabled it.

Why am I having this error message? Is that normal? What`s MSDTC use?

Is transactionScope SQLSecver specific?

Comment: Before someone posting a 500 words answer here, why do you want to use transactionscope?

Comment: I am using transaction scope as I am having nested transactions and NHIbernate doesn`t seem to support nested transactions.

Answer (score 1):

TransactionScope will treat your transaction as distributed if you use more than one connection within the same scope, therefore requiring MSDTC to be enabled. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759163/common-gotchas-when-using-transactionscope-and-ms-dtc) for more information on TransactionScope.

Generally, if you don't need distributed transactions, you can just use NHibernate's ITransactions instead. Take a look at the [NHibernate reference documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html) for lots of examples of NHibernate transactions.