# How can i handle connections to different databases inside a single transaction scope

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope, data-access

I'm trying to access data from two different databases inside a transactionscope.
But while executing any query on the second database , i get "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction." error

```
using(TransactionScope scope=new TransactionScope())
{
     Insert();//Inserts to database A
     Select();//Selects from database B - error while executing this statement
}
```

Both the databases exist in the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL Server 2005, I think that will require a DTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) to be active on all machines. The 2 different connections will cause the Transaction to be Promoted from Local to Distributed.

Apparently, that is fixed on SQL Server 2008: [TransactionScope automatically escalating to MSDTC on some machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines)  Which version of SQL Server are you using?

see [A ConnectionScope class](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dataaccess/archive/2006/02/14/532026.aspx)

[Common Gotchas when using TransactionScope and MS DTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759163/common-gotchas-when-using-transactionscope-and-ms-dtc)