# How to maintain transactions in two different databases

Tags: asp.net

I have to maintain transactions between two different databases. I need to rollback if there is any error occurred in Database1 then all changes in database2 should be rollback.

I have two connection string in my web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on if you need **distributed transactions** between two database server instances, or transactions between two databases in a single instance. In the first case you'll need a transaction manager like MSDTC, but in the second case the database server should be able to do the job by itself.

[TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) will escalate the transaction to MSDTC if necessary. The rules for this are somewhat subtle. If the two databases are on a single SQL Server 2008 instance, you shouldn't need MSDTC.

#### See also:

- [TransactionScope automatically
  escalating to MSDTC on some
  machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines)
- [Common Gotchas when
  using TransactionScope and MS DTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759163/common-gotchas-when-using-transactionscope-and-ms-dtc)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class:

```
using(var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    // TODO: your DB queries here
    tx.Complete();
}
```