# Sql Server 2014 sp_reset_connection behavior inside transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2014, isolation-level

What is the behavior of **sp_reset_connection** when it is run inside a transaction? I am looking for clarification so I can decide if I need to restructure my code, or if I can leave it as is.

I have a c# application that uses an ORM(Petapoco) that doesn't seem to respect the ambient transaction(System.Transactions.TransactionScope). I can see the transaction beginning in Sql Profiler, but before every call in the transaction the ORM is sending a **sp_reset_connection** call. I am also seeing the Transaction Commit event in Sql Profiler when my ambient transaction is completed.

I have seen other questions on StackOverflow that suggest the Transaction Isolation scope is reset when **sp_reset_connection** is called (see: [What does “exec sp_reset_connection” mean in Sql Server Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641120/what-does-exec-sp-reset-connection-mean-in-sql-server-profiler)), but I can't find any info on what happens specifically when **sp_reset_connection** is called inside of a transaction.

Comment: Take a look at answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187632/transactionscope-avoiding-distributed-transactions

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for, but thank you. I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sp_reset_connection` stored procedure is not well documented since it's an internal stored procedure and never called directly. Be aware that it may change or be removed in the future without notice. That being said, it is useful to know a little about the internals for troubleshooting and correlating activity trace data.

The purpose of the proc is to restore connection environment state to that of a newly opened connection to support connection pooling. The client API specifies whether a connection is to be reset by setting either the `RESETCONNECTION` or `RESETCONNECTIONSKIPTRAN` bits of the [TDS protocol status field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd358342.aspx) when a request is issued on a newly reused connection from the pool. SQL Server internally invokes the `sp_reset_connection` RPC you see in a trace when either of those flags are set.

The TDS protocol documentation desribes these flags so we can infer this is what `sp_reset_connection` does under the covers. Below is the an excerpt from the documentation:

> RESETCONNECTION (Introduced in TDS 7.1) (From client to server) Reset
>   this connection before processing event. Only set for event types
>   Batch, RPC, or Transaction Manager request. If clients want to set
>   this bit, it MUST be part of the first packet of the message. This
>   signals the server to clean up the environment state of the connection
>   back to the default environment setting, effectively simulating a
>   logout and a subsequent login, and provides server support for
>   connection pooling. This bit SHOULD be ignored if it is set in a
>   packet that is not the first packet of the message.
>
> This status bit MUST NOT be set in conjunction with the
>   RESETCONNECTIONSKIPTRAN bit. Distributed transactions and isolation
>   levels will not be reset. 0x10
>
> RESETCONNECTIONSKIPTRAN (Introduced in TDS 7.3) (From client to
>   server) Reset the connection before processing event but do not modify
>   the transaction state (the state will remain the same before and after
>   the reset). The transaction in the session can be a local transaction
>   that is started from the session or it can be a distributed
>   transaction in which the session is enlisted. This status bit MUST NOT
>   be set in conjunction with the RESETCONNECTION bit. Otherwise
>   identical to RESETCONNECTION.

The low-level client API (SqlClient here) indirectly controls the behavior of `sp_reset_connection` by setting those flags as needed. When a connection is reused outside a `TransactionScope`, the `RESETCONNECTION` flag is set as can be seen in this network packet trace (Wireshark):

[image]

Below is a trace of the first request issued on a reused connection from within the scope of a `TransactionScope` using block:

[image]

As you can see, the reset within `TransactionScope` will not rollback the transaction. Consequently, even if your ORM follows an open/execute/close pattern for data access, your outer `TransactionScope` transaction context will be honored. The transction will be committed as long as you invoke `TransactionScope.Complete` before exiting the transaction scope. You can include a TM Commit Tran completed event to your Profiler trace to see the commit when the `TransactionScope` exits.

BTW, Profiler/SQL trace is deprecated. Use Extended Events instead going forward. Also, as suggested in the other answer, be sure to specify the desired transaction isolation level (e.g. read committed) when you use TransactionScope. The default is serializable which can have side effects like unnecessary blocking and deadlocks. I suggest you use serializable only if you specifically need that strict level of isolation.