# c# EntityFramework: TransactionScope over two different databases on same server with DTC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, distributed-transactions

I have basicly the same Situation as here described here [Multiple databases(datacontext) on same server without MS DTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718360/multiple-databasesdatacontext-on-same-server-without-ms-dtc)

like:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var entities = new ContextA())
    {
        // do smth. here
    }

    using (var entities = new ContextB())
    {
        // do smth. there
    }
}
```

Both, ContextB and ContextA are located on the same MS SQL Server (V. 13.0.4206.0). The c# code is executed from remote Workstation. Server and Worksation are both in same domain network.
But when ContextB is trying to do it's first manipulation, it raises the following error:

> The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from
>   the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible
>   causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for
>   the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their
>   NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled
>   for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8004D02B)

It does not make any difference if I change the order of tasks; say first doing smth. on ContextB, then on ContextA: In that case the error raises when manipulating database from ContextA.
Without transaction scope all works fine (but of course without transaction).
I've checked firewall settings on Server: Predefined rule for Distributed Transaction Coordinator are enabled for domain and private network. I've checked also DTC properites:

Network DTC Access: true

Allow Inbound: true

AllowOutbound: true

What is wrong? It looks so simple, did I oversee something?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be in a hurry to let a remote workstation get involved in a DTC operation - that sounds risky; but: does dtcping work from that workstation to the server?

Comment: And do you need to get DTC involved at all? Since databases are on the same server, maybe you can do that without DTC?

Comment: @MarcGravell Played arround with the dtcping utitlity an came to a conclusion - see thread answer

Comment: @Evk The dtc is implicitly raised from by the .NET transaction framework ..., so actually I cannot influence its behavoiur ...

Comment: I heard that you can use the same connection string and then use ChangeDatabase method. In that case, because connection strings are identical - DTC should not be involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: Needs to activate predefined firewall rule 'Distributed Transaction Coordinator' on Worksation, where the c# code runs, too.

*I wasn't aware that the database server will open a connection back to the transaction initializer (which was my workstation). It seems in this situation, that the transaction initializer inherits the role as coordinator - not the server.*

Thank you for the given hints!