# Creating a database connection for every database insert - High SQL server memory usage

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have recently changed my web app to create a database connection per command instead of creating one connection and just reusing it for all commands. I used this code this afternoon and my database memory went up to 24GB usage peforming about 8k inserts. My code is like this (semi pseudo code):

```
public int ExecSQL(string SQLStr)
{
    using (SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(MyConStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLStr, Con))
        {
            return Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

using (TransactionScope TX = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    //Loop and perform 8000 x
    int ID = ExecSQL("insert into something (column) output unique_id values ('data')").
    // I also perform 1 or 2 selects per insert based on the ID returned from the insert. I don't use a .Supress for my inserts.
}
```

Could this of caused the high database memory usage? I was under the impression it should create 100 connections (default) then just keep re-using it but I am guessing I am missing something.

Answered: Ran the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as DBName, 
    COUNT(dbid) as NumberOfConnections,
    loginame as LoginName
FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid, loginame
```

and there is only one open connection for my database so this isn't causing the issue. Now to find out what is ..

Comment: The connection pooling will re-use the connection, so I don't think this is a problem.  Did anything else change?

Comment: I changed my code to use Datasets instead of SqlReader but I don't think that would do it as its database memory. I will test it again tomorrow. It could be that something else was causing it. I also changed my inserts to `output unique_id`, I don;t know if this adds lots of overhead ...

Comment: Why create a separate connection for each insert?

Comment: @beargle this is the best practice http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254507.aspx

Comment: @the_joric I don't see anything in that page advising separate connections for each `SqlCommand`...what am I missing?

Comment: OK, I missed the part about 8000 inserts being a 'test'...I assumed this was a normal app function and these should be batched.

Comment: R u aware that [TransactionScope creates by default serializable transactions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/06/03/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx)? And also multiple connections opened from a single TransactionScope enroll in distributed transaction (two phase commit) ?

Comment: @beargle I think that if commands are executed in a loop then single connection would be better, so you are correct :).

Comment: @RemusRusanu even if those connections are made for a single SQL server?

Comment: Can you explain a little more please Remus? I am getting rather confused, should I be using 1 connection and sharing it between all the commands here or creating 1 connection per command?

Comment: @the_joric: even then. There is no need for an external coordinator in such case, but is still a distributed transaction.

Comment: @webnoob: you should avoid using more than one connection in a transaction scope at all cost. You should avoid closing and opening connections unnecessarily (even when pooled, closing and opening has a cost).

Comment: @the_joric: for a longer post discussing this topic see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1693270/105929

Comment: @Remus - So I guess if I had a overloaded ExecSQL that allowed me to pass a SqlConnection param I could decide beforehand if I wanted to use a shared connection on the "bunch" of queries being performed but by default it will .Open() and .Close() each one.

Comment: @Remus I am also using the code as suggested in the link to cretae my TransactionScope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADO.NET uses [connection pools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx), so multiple `SqlConnection` objects with the same connection strings reuse the same physical database connection. Hardly your memory increase was caused by using `new SqlConnection()`

Comment: so `new SqlConnection` won't be causing the problem?

Comment: As far as I know -- it should not.

Comment: From what I can see you are correct. The memory on the server now seems to be Ok so I am going to go out on a limb and blame someone else for their bad timing on using all the memory :)