# How to use TransactionScope in SQLCLR without escalation to MSDTC

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlclr

A lot of our DAL code uses TransactionScope for transactions. That works great but there is a problem when i use this DAL code from inside an SQLCLR procedure. The Transaction is escalated to MSDTC what i don't want.

The Problem can be reproduced easily:

1. CLR Implementation

   ```
   [SqlProcedure]
   public static void ClrWithScope(string cmdText)
   {
       /* escalates to MSDTC when a transaction is already open */
       using ( var scope = new TransactionScope())
       {
           using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true;"))
           {
               connection.Open();
               using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection))
               {
                   SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(cmd);
               }
           }
           scope.Complete();
       }
   }

   [SqlProcedure]
   public static void ClrWithTrans(string cmdText)
   {
       /* works as expected (without MSDTC escalation ) */
       using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true;"))
       {
           connection.Open();
           using (var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
           {
               using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connection, tx))
               {
                   SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(cmd);
                   tx.Commit();
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. SQL script used to execute the CLR procedure

   ```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

   exec dbo.ClrWithTrans "select * from sys.tables";
   exec dbo.ClrWithScope "select * from sys.tables"; /* <- DOES NOT WORK! */

   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   ```
3. the error

   ```
   Msg 6549, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ClrWithScope, Line 0
   A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'clrClrWithScope': 
   System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: Die Transaktion wurde abgebrochen. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException: MSDTC on server 'BLABLA' is unavailable. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: MSDTC on server 'BLABLA' is unavailable.
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
      bei System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.StandardEventSink.HandleErrors()
      bei System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.ClrLevelContext.SuperiorTransaction.Promote()
   System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException: 
      bei System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.ClrLevelContext.SuperiorTransaction.Promote()
      bei System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
      bei System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
   System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException: 
      bei System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CreateAbortingClone(InternalTransaction tx)
      bei System.Transactions.DependentTransaction..ctor(IsolationLevel isoLevel, InternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean blocking)
      bei System.Transactions.Transaction.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption cloneOption)
      bei System.Transactions.TransactionScope.SetCurrent(Transaction newCurrent)
      bei System.Transactions.TransactionScope.PushScope()
      bei System.Transactions.TransactionScope..ctor(TransactionScopeOption scopeOption)
      bei Giag.Silo.Data.SqlClr.ClrWithScope(String cmdText)
   . User transaction, if any, will be rolled back.
   ```

WIHTOUT the "BEGIN TRANSACTION" statement, the dbo.ClrWithScope call works OK. I suppose that the transaction started by SQLServer is not considered while enlisting in the .Net Framework.

Is there a solution to get arround this. An idea is to manually create an SqlTransaction and make the TransactionScope to use this transaction, but i don't know how to do this. Another solution would be to make a special case in all of the DAL code (not really funny to implement).

Any ideas ?

Comment: try putting the `Connection` around the `Scope`

Comment: @Magnus But that doesn't (automatically) enlist the Connection into the ambient transaction, which is the whole purpose of the TransactionScope, isn't it?

Comment: Christian.K is right. The DAL code is using TransactionScope and SqlConnection a lot. Of course it is possible to rewrite the whole codebase in DAL but it is not nice.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why is it escalating to DTC at all?  That should only happen if you are connecting/executing on a second Server/Instance, but there's no indication of that anywhere in here?

Comment: @RBarryYoung. Under some circunsances (nesting, SqlServer versions) the Transaction is escalation although only one connection string is used. See [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines?rq=1) for more information. Here, the transaction is only escalated when BEGIN TRANSACTION in SQL Script is used.

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14318/4675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TransactionScope within SQL CLR will always promote/escalate to a MSDTC transaction.  There does not appear to be any way around this, even in SQL 2012.

From TechNet regarding SQL CLR and TransactionScope (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131084.aspx)

> TransactionScope should be used only when local and remote data
>   sources or external resource managers are being accessed. This is
>   because TransactionScope always causes transactions to promote, even
>   if it is being used only within a context connection.