# TransactionScope promoting to MSDTC although I am using the same connection string

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2008-r2, transactionscope, entity-framework-4.3, msdtc

I have two repositories that point to the same SQL Server 2008 R2 (10.50.2550.0) database. One repository is based on Entity Framework, the other uses regular SqlConnection. I need to perform an operation that involves both, so I have used a `TransactionScope` to keep them in the same transaction:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead }))
{
   _repoA.DoStuff();
   _repoB.DoStuff();
}
```

Since I use the same connection string in both:

```
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=myid;Password=mypass;Asynchronous Processing=true"
```

I was expecting that [SQL Server 2008 R2 could use multiple connections without scalating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines).
Unfortunately I get an exception saying:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred   Message=MSDTC on server
>   'MyComputer' is unavailable.   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060   Class=16   LineNumber=1   Number=8501
>   Procedure=""   Server=(local)   State=2   StackTrace:
>          at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

What could be the problem?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found why. Entity Framework is modifying my connection string to:

```
"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mydb;User Id=myid;Password=mypass;Asynchronous Processing=true;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"
```

And that is causing the promotion to MSDTC!

In order to avoid this, I have set up my own ["Application Name"](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/use-application-name-sql-server) in the connection string and it works now.

Cheers.