# Does TransactionScope always use local DTC?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, transactionscope, msdtc

The first opened connection, created within TransactionScope requires DTC to be enabled.

I'm aware that multiple connections can promote transaction to distributed, but I get exception before another connection is created. `TransactionManager.DistributedTransactionStarted` event is not raised as well.

Any hints why this can happen will be helpful.

This SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines) only assures me that multiple opened connections to SQL Server 2012 shouldn't promote to DTC, yet I have problem with one connection.

Comment: "but I get exception before another connection is created" - what does the exception *say*? Personally, though, I'm tempted to just say "use basic ADO.NET transactions if this proves problematic"

Comment: It depends on DTC network access settings: either "Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed." or "The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions." But I cannot understand why DTC is required at all.

Comment: I'd gladly use transactions but current system's design requires considerable change (under stealths refactoring now) to enable the notion of ambient transaction.

Comment: my hypothesis: it is demanding that DTC is *available*, leaving the "can I actually do it the easy way via LTM" as a secondary concern. Have you tried making DTC available just to see whether it (DTC) is actually used?

Comment: Tried DTCPing and got RPC error. But had no time to research what causes the problem. antivirus and firewall are off. Rpc locator is on.

Comment: @MarcGravell That's f...n "brilliant". Old entlib API creates connections internally. dotPeek+stacktrace helped. Well, things are worse than I previously thought =)

Comment: one more reason to dislike entlib... if only there were more modern, simpler, more efficient, less abstracted, smaller, data access tools - maybe something like "dapper" ;p