# Avoiding Escalation to DTC for SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, msdtc, escalation

I was testing my code by disabling MSDTC and wanted to make sure that no transaction within my code gets escalated([Trace why a transaction is escalated to DTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506733/trace-why-a-transaction-is-escalated-to-dtc)). Now the code seems to work fine and there isn't any peoblem related to DTC. Should I be comfortable with it, that the code will work fine and there will be no escalation when it is deployed. It will be deployed on SQL Azure, and EF 4.5 is being used for Data Access.

According to this post [TransactionScope automatically escalating to MSDTC on some machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines) that SQL Server 2008 can use multiple connection without escalating, I just wanted to be sure if it applies for SQL Azure as well.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've encountered this problem with Azure too. Our experience while looking into it over the last few months has been consistent:

Disable MSDTC on your development machine and if your code works reliably when connected to SQL 2008 you won't see the problem in your deployment. Our web application has up to 300k unique visitors per day and we've never seen the issue in the live environment when we've fixed it locally.